# Window between desktop files and background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My app is a window that sits between the desktop icons and the wallpaper. To achieve this I used

```
 [self setLevel:kCGDesktopWindowLevel - 1];
```

However, my window is not interactive, I cannot move it around with my mouse? Any ideas why?

Mouse events are not firing

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Helloworld");
}
```

Is something else intercepting the mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. 
The window level is lower than the desktop so it won't receive mouse events because the desktop intercepts them.

You might try using a global event monitor when your app is active and catch mouse events. But it's a hack already.